# How do I create endgame tablebases?

Tags: endgame, software, tablebases

What software can I use to create and verify endgame databases? I want to create my own tablebases from scratch on my PC - I'm specifically looking for open-source software that I can modify to support variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [syzygy1/tb](https://github.com/syzygy1/tb) to create and verify tablebases.  Never tried to modify it so not sure how easy that is.